# Extracting a PDF from Gitbook Using Foregebox

Tags: pdf-generation, gitbook, commandbox

I am trying to use [ForgeBox](https://www.forgebox.io/view/gitbook-exporter)

to export my gitbook as a pdf. However, it is asking me to export the contents of your book from the Gitbook.com website. Under Advanced, expand Danger Zone and click the red Export button. Make sure you don't hit Delete instead! You will download a zip fie containing JSON files and images that describe all of the content in your book.

You can point to the zip when you run a command.

I however don't see this option at all. Can someone help me with this. I have access to the github repo of the gitbook, should I just download the .zip of the repository instead.